# ASP.NET - caching user privileges

Tags: asp.net

I'm sorry for my english.

In my ASP.NET MVC application I have users controlled by ASP.NET Membership and user groups which are stored in database by means of my business-logic. Also, I implemented ACL (access control list) architecture to control user access to entities in my application so i have a number of records (stored in DB table) of structure User-Object-Privilegy-Value.

To ensure that a user has access to certain entity (or object) i need to re-create ever time the hierarchy of all groups where the user is the participant and find all privileges for that subjects.

In the purpose of optimization i need to cache that information in the application cache but i also need to monitor if any user, user group or privilegy has changed to invalidate that cached records.

I could implement it by some ways but i'd like to know the better way.

Did anyone has the same expirience? What is the best solution for caching user privileges?

Answer (score 0):

There are built-in caching tools, but none that will cache and invalidate a specific, custom structure with enough knowledge to handle a hierarchy as you describe automatically. You will have to write your own.

However, you can still use the built-in CacheDependency system to be the underlying framework. You will have to extend the class and subscribe to the various change notifiers yourself.